# JavaFX: stage.setOnCloseRequest() not working

Tags: java, javafx, event-listener

I have a main window on top of which an error dialog opens. At that point an overlay is displayed between the main window and the error dialog (part of the main window stage).
`mainWindowOverlay.setManaged(true)`
When the error dialog is closed, the overlay should disappear.
`errorStage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> overlayOff())`
I don't know if the close event isn' t registered or if there's another problem but the overlay stays after the error dialog has been closed.

Any ideas?

**controllerMainWindow.java**

```
package packageA;
import [...];

public class controllerMainWindow extends AbstractController
{
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainWindowOverlay;
    @FXML
    private Button btnError;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void initialize()
    {
        mainWindowOverlay.setManaged(false);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
            try {
                if (event.getSource().equals(btnError)) {
                    FXMLLoader errorLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                    errorLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("errorDialog.fxml"));
                    controllerErrorDialog errorController = new controllerErrorDialog();
                    errorLoader.setController(errorController);
                    Parent layout;
                    layout = errorLoader.load();
                    Scene errorScene = new Scene(layout);
                    Stage errorStage = new Stage();
                    errorStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    errorController.setStage(errorStage);
                    if(this.main!=null) {
                        errorStage.initOwner(main.getPrimaryStage());
                    }
                    customerServiceOverlay.setManaged(true);
                    errorStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    errorStage.setScene(errorScene);
                    errorStage.setX(750);
                    errorStage.setY(425);
                    errorStage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> overlayOff());
                    errorStage.showAndWait();
                }
            } catch (IOException exceptionHandleButtonAction) {
                System.out.println("Error on handleButtonAction.");
                exceptionHandleButtonAction.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void overlayOff()
    {
        customerServiceOverlay.setManaged(false);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

**controllerErrorDialog.java**

```
package packageA;
import [...];

public class controllerErrorDialog extends AbstractController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button btnClose;
    @FXML
    private Stage stage = null;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {

    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setStage(Stage stage)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        stage.fireEvent(new javafx.stage.WindowEvent(stage, 
        javafx.stage.WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
        stage.close();
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `customerServiceOverlay.setVisible(false)`? Or to remove it from whatever its parent is?

Comment: Also, would it not be better to use `stage.setOnHidden(...)`?

Comment: customerServiceOverlay.setManaged(false); will not hide the overlay. You can use e. g. setVisible(false) or remove the overlay node or use a StackPane and call .toBack();

Comment: @James_D I don't quite remember why but in an earlier version there was a specific reason why I used setManaged. In its current state, the result is probably the same?

Comment: Is the handler being invoked?

Comment: same procedure as always: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions

Comment: Thanks everyone, replacing setManaged with setVisible already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by @James_D and @anko.

[image]